# Generative model for random covariance matrices to fit hierarchical data

Tags: mixed-model, pca, multilevel-analysis, covariance-matrix

I have a multivariate dataset with M groups of data, each consisting of N iid measurements of p variables. Say I take the N measurements from a single widget, and M corresponds to the number of widgets I measured.

I do PCA on each of the M groups of data and observe variation in the principle components (and their associated eigenvalues) across the M groups. For example, I may see that the first component is very consistent across groups, while the second components has a lot of variation, etc.

I’d like to model the data hierarchically as multivariate normal with per-group  covariance, so,

$X_{mn} \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{Σ}_m), \quad X \in \mathbb{R}^{p}, \quad m \in {1,2,…,M}, \quad n \in {1,2,…,N}$

$Σ_m \sim \mathcal{P},\quad Σ \in \mathbb{R}^{pxp}$

$\mathbf{X_m} = \left[X_{m1}, X_{m2}, ..., X_{mN} \right], \quad \mathbf{X_m}^T\mathbf{X_m} = \mathbf{Q_m}\mathbf{\Lambda_m}\mathbf{Q_m}^{-1}$

I’m looking for a way to model the distribution $\mathcal{P}$ over covariance matrices that reflects the actual variation in eigenvectors and eignevalues seen in the data. Ideally the variation in both eigenvectors and eigenvalues would be roughly "uniform", with bounds defined by the data, though I don't know how to define that formally.

Note, I don’t need to perform inference, so am not worried about computational issues. I just need an explainable way to generate plausible synthetic samples.